# Android button selector transition exitFade problems

Tags: android, xml

I am working on my first app and I have a problem... I found that there is a xml tag called ***android:exitFadeDuration=" "*** and I want to use to use transition delay between my custom button views.

This is my button selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="125">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_btn_on"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_btn_on"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_btn_off" />
</selector>
```

This is my **alert_btn_off**:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkestMain" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkerMain" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This is my **alert_btn_on**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorMainDark" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/darkerMain" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The only difference between btnOn and btnOff is bottom border, which is turning into blue... Here is what I got on ***android:exitFadeDuration="125"***

**Button default**

[image]

**Button state pressed A**

[image]]

**Button state pressed B**

[image]

I like this transition, but I need to put transition only for borders, is there any way to accomplish this ?? By the way the same thing happens if I use `enterFadeTransition`.

Comment: "I need to put transition only for borders": What is your question? Why isn't A your solution already? Please DETAIL what you want to achieve.

Comment: The thing is when I press the button btnDefault goes first, btnStatePressed A goes second and right after that goes btnStatePressed B, so it flashes is blue color... I need only transit border, do you understand ?? Sorry :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have an animation only for the borders of your button and not for the full background, you have to limit the animation to the borders.

You will have only one layer list called `/drawable/alert_btn.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/statelist"/>

    <item android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And `/drawable/statelist.xml` will look like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="500">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```